# How to update Telegram source message when Destination message Edited or Deleted

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm implementing a code to forward Telegram messages from one channel to another channel I can forward messages but I cannot find a way to update the Source messages when the destination message edited or deleted

Here is the code i already have this is working fine

```
client = TelegramClient('telegramfw', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
@client.on(events.MessageEdited)
async def handler(event):
    chat = await event.get_chat()

    chat_id = event.chat_id
    print(chat_id)
    if chat_id == -1001629488043:
        if event.photo:
            await client.send_file(-1001567215170, event.photo,  caption=event.raw_text)
        elif event.video:
            await client.send_file(-1001567215170, event.video, caption=event.raw_text)
        else:
            msg = event.raw_text
            print(msg)
            msg_id_source = event.message.id
            await client.send_message(-1001567215170, msg)


client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

**Is there any way to do this im new to python and telethon it is grate help some one can help with**

Answer (score 0):

```
#@client.on(events.NewMessage)
#@client.on(events.MessageEdited)
#could delete it and add

client.add_event_handler(handler,events.NewMessage)
client.add_event_handler(handler,events.MessageEdited)
```

but i don't think it is a elegent way

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solutions i dont know is this the correct way but it solve my problem

Need to keep message id's in a database and telethon have an option to get edited message

i used SQLite for DB that is inbuilt with python

here is the code i use

```
@client.on(events.MessageEdited)
async def handler(event):
    for row in cur.execute("SELECT * FROM keepmsgid where sid=:id", {"id": event.id}):
        Source_message_id = row[0]
        await client.edit_message(destination_id, Source_message_id, event.raw_text)
```

Let me know if any one need any help with this

Answer (score -1):

i'm also want to know that how to add two decorate on a handler,please

Comment: Please do not answer posts with "I'm also having this problem". Instead if you have more details about the problem, post them in a comment under the original question